# "The command line is too long" with subprocess.run

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'm trying to execute the `subprocess.run` command.

I have a parameter that's very large - it's basically a SQL statement more than 10000 characters long.

Executing

```
subprocess.run(["cmd", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9], shell=True)
```

returns an error `The command line is too long.`

It seems the limit for total length of parameters is around 8000 chars.

Running python on Windows:

```
Python 3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Is there a way to pass such parameter?

Comment: why don't you put that in a file and read it from there?

Comment: I'm trying to execute an external tool that requires the query to be passed as command-line parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.
Save your parameters into file (e.g. params.txt), then:

```
set /p PARAMS= < params.txt
cmd %PARAMS%
```

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Hi @aramcpp! 

Thank for the suggestion. Yes, this seems be one option how to do it. I need to execute 2 run commands. Like this:  

subprocess.run(["set", "/p PARAMS= < param.txt"], shell=True)
subprocess.run(["someprogram.exe", "%PARAMS%"], shell=True)

Comment: I will accept this answer for now. :) It's not ideal (a file needs to be generated, etc.), but it's the only solution I found so far.